# routing error for root and get pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a rails app and This is my first time working with ruby or any server-side programming language. I connected to localhost:3000 and everything went well. I went to change the routing for my home page as well as create some new ones but I'm having an issue of gettign them to preview and I keep Getting error messages. Here is the snippet from my routes.rb file

My routes.rb

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do

   root 'pages#home'
   get 'about' => 'pages#about'
   post 'forum' => 'pages#forum' 
   get 'contact-us' => 'pages#contact-us'
    
 end
```

I'm still relatively new To programming as well as stack overflow so I can't embed images yet So it will only have a link. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Don't take pictures of your code or output. Edit your post, indent your code by at least 4 spaces, and paste it directly into your post.

Comment: You have used the same image twice, and instead of images, its always better to paste in the code

Comment: Further to the above comments, the image you have posted is of the navigation tree in your text editor, and not of your code.

Comment: To elaborate @Phiip's point, readers cannot copy and paste your code if it's shown in a pic, and if the pic is at a link, the link could in future be broken.

Comment: Along with comments above, can you post the actual error you are getting?

Comment: I updated and put the code in there I'm getting a no route matches error for any of the pages I've created

Answer (score 0):

1 - Try to avoid `fat arrow`

2- Controller name should not contain -(dash) instead use _(Underscore) example(contact-us should be contact_us)

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
root 'pages#home'
get '/about', to: 'pages#about', as: :about
post '/forum', to: 'pages#forum', as: :forum    
get '/contact_us', to: 'pages#contact_us', as: :contact_us
```

end

3- After changing this run `rake routes` at your console in your project directory , you will get list of routes

4- you can now use routes helper of `prefix_path` example (root_path, about_path or forum_path, contact_path)

Comment: Thank you I will try that out.